# How to paste source code to vim without error format?

Tags: vim, indentation

When I copy a python code, and paste to vim. the indents are all error.
but I paste into emacs or gedit, it is right.

that is difficult to describle, let's see the screenshot.
Notice:the blue and yellow line is just use the "indent guides plugin".
[image: the screenshot]

This is the source code example:

```
import threading
import time
class timer(threading.Thread): #The timer class is derived from the class threading.Thread
    def __init__(self, num, interval):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_num = num
        self.interval = interval
        self.thread_stop = False

    def run(self): #Overwrite run() method, put what you want the thread do here
        while not self.thread_stop:
            print 'Thread Object(%d), Time:%s/n' %(self.thread_num, time.ctime())
            time.sleep(self.interval)
    def stop(self):
        self.thread_stop = True


def test():
    thread1 = timer(1, 1)
    thread2 = timer(2, 2)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    thread1.stop()
    thread2.stop()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Automatic indenting kicked in.

The easiest way to disable it is: `:set paste`

> ```
> :help paste
>
> 'paste'                 boolean (default off)      
>                         global
>                         {not in Vi}
>     Put Vim in Paste mode.  This is useful if you want to cut or copy
>     some text from one window and paste it in Vim.  This will avoid
>     unexpected effects.
>     Setting this option is useful when using Vim in a terminal, where Vim
>     cannot distinguish between typed text and pasted text.  In the GUI, Vim
>     knows about pasting and will mostly do the right thing without 'paste'
>     being set.  The same is true for a terminal where Vim handles the
>     mouse clicks itself.
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. If I open Paste mode, Is there any influence to the other things, for example such as edit code and so on?

Comment: it just disables all settings related to input text formatting. see `:help paste`

Answer (score 16):

Karoly's answer is correct regarding the `paste` option.

You can then add a mapping in your .vimrc to quickly enable/disable 'paste' option:

For example, I use
`set pastetoggle=<F10>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also let vim handle the situation automatically for you.
With the following in your `~\.vimrc`

```
let &t_SI .= "\<Esc>[?2004h"
let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[?2004l"

inoremap <special> <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin()

function! XTermPasteBegin()
  set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
  set paste
  return ""
endfunction
```

you can paste freely without worrying about the auto-indentions.

If you work in tmux, then you have to write instead the following

```
function! WrapForTmux(s)
  if !exists('$TMUX')
    return a:s
  endif

  let tmux_start = "\<Esc>Ptmux;"
  let tmux_end = "\<Esc>\\"

  return tmux_start . substitute(a:s, "\<Esc>", "\<Esc>\<Esc>", 'g') . tmux_end
endfunction

let &t_SI .= WrapForTmux("\<Esc>[?2004h")
let &t_EI .= WrapForTmux("\<Esc>[?2004l")

function! XTermPasteBegin()
  set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
  set paste
  return ""
endfunction

inoremap <special> <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin()
```

The source is [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/if9mda/automatically-set-paste-mode-in-vim-when-pasting-in-insert-mode) if you would like to read more.