# Pasting texts in vim

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to paste source code to vim without error format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822618/how-to-paste-source-code-to-vim-without-error-format)

In Vim, When I paste a text like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

It will be converted to:

```
line1
  line2
    line3
```

This usually happens when I copy a text from the web. How do I paste text as it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:set paste` to enable Paste mode. Then you can paste as much as you want without vim trying to autoindent it. When you are done, remember to disable Paste mode using `:set nopaste`.

Answer (score 1):

In insert mode, `C-r C-p *` will usually do what you want. You could also use the `noinvpaste` option.

Comment: "set noinvpaste" : Unknown Option noinvpaste

Comment: C-r C-p * Pastes nothing

Comment: This will only work if Vim was compiled with `clipboard`. You can test this by running `vim --version | grep '+clipboard'` or `:version` in Vim.